# How to get weekday with in out time if same time day in days to we will show like Monday-Tuesday 10:00-18:00

Tags: php

How to get weekday with in out time if same time day in days to we will show like  Monday-Tuesday  10:00-18:00
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[day] => Sunday
[in_time] =>
[out_time] =>
[active_day] => 0
)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [day] => Monday
        [in_time] => 10:00
        [out_time] => 18:00
        [active_day] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [day] => Tuesday
        [in_time] => 10:00
        [out_time] => 18:00
        [active_day] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [day] => Wednesday
        [in_time] => 12:00
        [out_time] => 16:00
        [active_day] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [day] => Thursday
        [in_time] => 12:00
        [out_time] => 16:00
        [active_day] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [day] => Friday
        [in_time] => 10:00
        [out_time] => 19:00
        [active_day] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [day] => Saturday
        [in_time] => 
        [out_time] => 
        [active_day] => 0
    )
```

)

Comment: can you elaborate more about the problem statement. Currently, not getting what actually you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create an associative array indexed by the time frames - and then aggregate the days by their time frame:

```php
<?php
$result = [];

foreach($list as $item)
{
  if ($item['active_day']) $result[$item['in_time'].'-'.$item['out_time'][] = $item['day'];
}

foreach($result as $time => $days)
{
  echo $days[0];
  $numDays = count($days);
  if ($numDays > 1) echo '-'.$days[$numDays - 1];
  echo ' '.$time."\n";
}
```